# can't implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener in activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-searchmanager

I want to add search functionally in my activity so i tried to implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener but it's showing error that create interface......

any other way to add search in action bar..please link me...

```
public class setting_1 extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_1, container, false);
    ImageView i1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.s_i_1_1);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First:


    `import android.widget.SearchView;`


Then implement your SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.